# Tekton: yq Task gives safelyRenameFile [ERRO] Failed copying from /tmp/temp & [ERRO] open /workspace/source permission denied error

Tags: kubernetes, replace, yq, tekton, openshift-pipelines

We have a Tekton pipeline and want to replace the `image` tags contents of our `deployment.yml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: microservice-api-spring-boot
spec:
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microservice-api-spring-boot
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: microservice-api-spring-boot
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: registry.gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot@sha256:5d8a03755d3c45a3d79d32ab22987ef571a65517d0edbcb8e828a4e6952f9bcd
          name: microservice-api-spring-boot
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8098
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gitlab-container-registry
```

Our Tekton pipeline uses the [yq Task from Tekton Hub](https://hub.tekton.dev/tekton/task/yq) to replace the `.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image` with the `"$(params.IMAGE):$(params.SOURCE_REVISION)"` name like this:

```
- name: substitute-config-image-name
  taskRef:
    name: yq
  runAfter:
    - fetch-config-repository
  workspaces:
    - name: source
      workspace: config-workspace
  params:
    - name: files
      value:
      - "./deployment/deployment.yml"
    - name: expression
      value: .spec.template.spec.containers[0].image = \"$(params.IMAGE)\":\"$(params.SOURCE_REVISION)\"
```

Sadly the yq Task doesn't seem to work, it produces a green
`Step completed successfully`, but shows the following errors:

```
16:50:43 safelyRenameFile [ERRO] Failed copying from /tmp/temp3555913516 to /workspace/source/deployment/deployment.yml
16:50:43 safelyRenameFile [ERRO] open /workspace/source/deployment/deployment.yml: permission denied
```

Here's also a screenshot from our Tekton Dashboard:

[image]

Any idea on how to solve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the way how the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/blob/master/Dockerfile) of https://github.com/mikefarah/yq now handles file permissions (for example [this fix](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/commit/adb61446061d8d376c2c2c50436db7d5e054d94d#diff-dd2c0eb6ea5cfc6c4bd4eac30934e2d5746747af48fef6da689e85b752f39557) among others). The `0.3` version of the Tekton yq Task uses the image https://hub.docker.com/layers/mikefarah/yq/4.16.2/images/sha256-c6ef1bc27dd9cee57fa635d9306ce43ca6805edcdab41b047905f7835c174005 which produces the error.

One work-around to the problem could be the usage of the yq Task version `0.2` which you can apply via:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tektoncd/catalog/main/task/yq/0.2/yq.yaml
```

This one uses the older `docker.io/mikefarah/yq:4@sha256:34f1d11ad51dc4639fc6d8dd5ade019fe57cf6084bb6a99a2f11ea522906033b` and works without the error.

Alternatively you can simply create your own yq based Task that won't have the problem like this:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: replace-image-name-with-yq
spec:
  workspaces:
    - name: source
      description: A workspace that contains the file which need to be dumped.
  params:
    - name: IMAGE_NAME
      description: The image name to substitute
    - name: FILE_PATH
      description: The file path relative to the workspace dir.
    - name: YQ_VERSION
      description: Version of https://github.com/mikefarah/yq
      default: v4.2.0
  steps:
    - name: substitute-with-yq
      image: alpine
      workingDir: $(workspaces.source.path)
      command:
        - /bin/sh
      args:
        - '-c'
        - |
          set -ex
          echo "--- Download yq & add to path"
          wget https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/download/$(params.YQ_VERSION)/yq_linux_amd64 -O /usr/bin/yq &&\
              chmod +x /usr/bin/yq
          echo "--- Run yq expression"
          yq e ".spec.template.spec.containers[0].image = \"$(params.IMAGE_NAME)\"" -i $(params.FILE_PATH)
          echo "--- Show file with replacement"
          cat $(params.FILE_PATH)
      resources: {}
```

This custom Task simple uses the `alpine` image as base and [installs yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq#install) using the `Plain binary wget` download. Also it uses `yq` exactly as you would do on the command line locally, which makes development of your expression so much easier!

As a bonus it outputs the file contents so you can check the replacement results right in the Tekton pipeline!

You need to apply it with

```
kubectl apply -f tekton-ci-config/replace-image-name-with-yq.yml
```

And should now be able to use it like this:

```
- name: replace-config-image-name
  taskRef:
    name: replace-image-name-with-yq
  runAfter:
    - dump-contents
  workspaces:
    - name: source
      workspace: config-workspace
  params:
    - name: IMAGE_NAME
      value: "$(params.IMAGE):$(params.SOURCE_REVISION)"
    - name: FILE_PATH
      value: "./deployment/deployment.yml"
```

Inside the Tekton dashboard it will look somehow like this and output the processed file:

[image]